# query inbound / outbound IPv4 packet count statistics of network card programatically in c#

Tags: c#, networking, ip, wmi-query, performancecounter

I want to get statistics about sent and received packet counts (IP level :  including TCP, UDP, etc) of a network card.

How can I query that information from windows?

Answer (score 1):

First you have

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

Next you have:

```
var iFaceArr = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
NetworkInterface iface = iFaceArr[0];
IPv4InterfaceStatistics iFaceStats = iface.GetIPv4Statistics();
```

Then you have these variables:

```
iFaceStats.UnicastPacketsReceived;
iFaceStats.UnicastPacketsSent;
iFaceStats.NonUnicastPacketsReceived;
iFaceStats.NonUnicastPacketsSent;
```

[Reference](http://www.m0interactive.com/archives/2008/02/06/how_to_calculate_network_bandwidth_speed_in_c_/)

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at [Pcap.Net](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net).

> ```
> Getting the list of Live Devices on the local host.
> Reading packets from Live Devices (Network Devices) and Offline Devices (Files) using the different WinPcap methods.
> Receiving statistics on the entire capture.
> Receiving statistics of packets instead of the full packets.
> Using different sampling methods.
> Applying Berkley Packet Filters.
> Sending packets to Live Devices directly or using WinPcap's send queues.
> Dumping packets to Pcap files.
> Using Enumerables to receive packets (and LINQ).
> ```

Note that winpcap driver will have to be installed on your system.

Comment: -1. SERIOUSLY? Install a driver for doing something that you can do out of the box with WMI? What happened to solid principles like keeping programs install only the bare necessity?

Comment: I guess it went out with KEEP IT SIMPLE SILLY and they broke up.

Answer (score -1):

WMI.

Not easy to use from C#, but possible.

Documentation for the needed class is at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/wmisdk/wmi/win32_perfformatteddata_tcpip_networkinterface.asp

Comment: I could not manage to open the hyperlink, could you please verify it is alive

Comment: :I viewed the properties of Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface class in MSDN, it appears most data are of type (value/s) that is packets per second or bytes per second and there is no CUMULATIVE count available?